# ASP.NET ListView: Calling a Javascript function from an OnItemClick event?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, listview

I need to get the click event of a ListView item to refresh another ListView without refresing the entire page. Basically use javascript to refresh ListView No.2 when a user clicks on any item of ListView no.1. Here's what I tried:

ListView 1:

```
<asp:ListView ID="LeftsideMessageList" runat="server" ItemPlaceholderID="itemPlaceHolder1"  DataKeyNames="id" OnSelectedIndexChanged="LeftsideMessageList_SelectedIndexChanged"  >
```

ListView 2 (which refreshes everytime any item of LV1 is clicked/selected)

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="videosUpdatePanel" runat="server" OnLoad="videosUpdatePanel_Load" > 
        <ContentTemplate>
             <asp:ListView ID="videosListView"  runat="server" ItemPlaceholderID="itemPlaceHolder1">
            //List view items and stuff
         </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

And my javascript:

```
<script
        type="text/javascript"> function GetVideos() { __doPostBack("<%=videosUpdatePanel.UniqueID %>", ""); } 
    </script>
```

I just have to simply call the GetVideos() javascript method to fire the videosUpdatePanel's C# OnLoad method:

```
protected void videosUpdatePanel_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        string email = Session["Username"].ToString();
        List<Activity> videos = BC.getMediaOfUser(email, "Video");

        videosListView.DataSource = videos;
        videosListView.DataBind();
}
```

Here's the procedure I have in mind:

> **Click/Select any item from LV1 -> Call the GetVideos() Javascript -> Call Update panel's OnLoad to refresh LV2**

Where I'm stuck at is, how do I call the GetVideos() function since ASP ListViews do not have a OnClick method? What is the method to call the ListView No.1's OnItemClick?

Comment: ListView 1 is populated dynamically or  it has static items.

Comment: @MairajAhmad  Dynamically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in simple method without additional JavaScript. use UpdatePanel Triggers.

http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/older-versions-getting-started/aspnet-ajax/understanding-asp-net-ajax-updatepanel-triggers

This link show detailed examples for triggers.

Answer (score 0):

Check **LeftsideMessageList** listviews rendering html. And add click event bind to row item. This event can call GetVideos function.

Comment: Your response isn't clear, mate. Could you elaborate a bit more please?